# Past simple or past coninuous?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, exam-questions, past-continuous

I Need to prove my teacher wrong.  We had an English test and there was this one task where we had to put the verbs in the right past tense (past simple or past continuous). So the sentence was:

> Susan ___ (photograph) places and people while she ____ (travel) in the Middle East.

My answer was:

> Susan photographed places and people while she was travelling in the Middle East.

And my teacher said it should be like that:

> Susan was photographing places and people while she was travelling in the Middle East.

Comment: Either makes sense (and neither seems wrong) to me as a native speaker of English, from NYC.

Comment: oh yeah i know, my keyboard is swiss so it capitalizes it automatically i‘m sorry 

Answer (score 1):

Both simple past and past continuous are fine, and you can even mix the two:

> Susan **photographed** places and people while she **traveled** in the Middle East.
>
> Susan **photographed** places and people while she **was traveling** in the Middle East.
>
> Susan **was photographing** places and people while she **traveled** in the Middle East.
>
> Susan **was photographing** places and people while she **was traveling** in the Middle East.

Some people may prefer to use the past continuous with "while", but all are grammatical. Each has a slightly different *nuance*, though the differences are pretty small.